# Collapsed terminology for simple logarithmic procedure

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value

During some computation, I had to rescale a value $x$ by taking the $\log_{10}(x)$. If $x$ was positive, I merely took the log, but if $x$ was negative i used -$\log_{10}(|x|)$.  Is there a shorter way to state that this was done using one equation with perhaps $\pm$ in it, or perhaps the $\mathrm{sgn}()$ function?  I would rather not write that I used both $\log_{10}(x)$ when $x>0$ and $-\log_{10}(|x|)$ when $x<0$.  I am thinking there's one equation to show this.

Comment: You mean $\text {sgn}(x)\times \log_{10}|x|$?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use $-\log|x|$ for $x<0$? What about for $|x| < 1$? As you've defined it, e.g. for $u > 0$, 
$$
-\log|-u| = -\log u = \log \frac1u.
$$
so $-u$ and $\frac1u$ produce the same value.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. It's actually $\mathrm{sgn}(u)\log(|u|+1)$, which simply goes negative and stays negative as soon as $u<0$. No issues with $<1$.